# Remove "All" from filter category and set another jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

My code is working fine but I want to remove "All" option from the filter and sent another as default.

HTML/PHP

```
    <section class="gallery ptb150">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="full-tpl each-element">
                <div class="grid-wrapper">
                    <div class="filter_container text-center">                            

                        <div class="filter-item active" data-filter="all">
                            All
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-item"  data-filter="Action">
                            Action
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-item" data-filter="arcade">
                            Arcade
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-item" data-filter="Casual">
                            Casual
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-item" data-filter="Card">
                            Board
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-item" data-filter="Puzzle">
                            Puzzle 
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-item" data-filter="sports">
                            Sports
                        </div>

                    </div>
                     <div id= "data" class="item_container relative mt40">

                                  <?php    
                                  $url = 'https://example.com/cms/api/index.php?id=1';
                                  $data = file_get_contents($url);
                                  $characters = json_decode($data, true);

                                  foreach($characters['gameslist'] as $key) {
                                       if($key['featured']==0)
                                          {  
                                  ?>
                                      <div class="item <?PHP echo $key['genre']; ?> col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                          <a href="<?PHP echo "game.php?id=".$key['id']; ?>" target="_blank" class="item-content">
                                              <div class="image-bl">
                                                  <img src="<?PHP echo $characters['baseurlthumbnailbanner'].$key['bannericon']; ?>" alt="">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="bottom-info text-center p30">
                                                  <div class="category fsize-14 fweight-700 uppercase">
                                                      <?PHP echo ucfirst($key['genre']); ?> 
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="img-name">
                                                      <h5 data-trim="40">
                                                         <?PHP echo $key['name']; ?> 
                                                      </h5>
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                          </a>
                                      </div>
                                  <?PHP
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      //echo "no game";
                                              }
                                              }
                                              ?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="username">

                                 </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="" style="color:red"></div>
            </section>
script

$( '.gallery' ).on( 'click', '.filter_container > div', function()
                        {
                            $( '.filter_container > div' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
                        } );

                        if( $( '.item_container' ).length )
                        {
                            var itemGrid = new Muuri( '.item_container', {
                                showDuration: 200,
                                hideDuration: 100,
                                showEasing: 'ease-out',
                                layout: {
                                    rounding: false
                                }
                            } );

                            $( '.filter_container .filter-item' ).on( 'click', function()
                            {
                                var filterClass = $( this ).data( 'filter' );
                                if( filterClass === 'all' )
                                {
                                    itemGrid.filter( '.item' );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    itemGrid.filter( '.' + filterClass );
                                }
                            } );
                        }
                    } );
```

On page load I don't want to fetch all data, load only one category at the first page load and other on clicks, that's why I am searching solution for this. Tried isotop but it didn't work for me.

Comment: If you are searching solution for this means you will code something for this solution. So if the code you pasted here works fine, we can't help you, it's all ok. If you try something different show us and show what error do you get.

Comment: <div class="filter-item active" data-filter="all">
                            All
                        </div>

Comment: I want to set default <div class="filter-item active" data-filter="Action">
                            Action
                        </div>

Comment: when I tried to change it, it loads all images in Action section

Comment: Update your question with your attemps and what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to load only 'Action' section on page load rather than 'All'...thank you

Comment: Ok now is clear, but we need what you have tried to achieve your goal. We need only relevant code, and what errors you get. Please read thi [mcve]

Comment: if( filterClass === 'arcade' )

Comment: it is not showing any error but shows all images in 'arcade' section

Comment: show what you have tried  to achieve your goal because if your code WORKS well we doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solve with adding buttons and some additional CSS and script

CSS

```
<style>
            .filterDiv {  
              display: none;
            }

            .show {
              display: block;
            }

            .container {  
              overflow: hidden;
            }

            /* Style the buttons */
            .btn {
              border: none;
              outline: none;
              padding: 12px 16px;
              background-color: #f1f1f1;
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            .btn:hover {
              background-color: #ddd;
            }

            .btn.active {
              background-color: #000;
              color: #000;
            }
            </style>
```

Script

```
          filterSelection("Action")
        function filterSelection(c) {
          var x, i;
          x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
          if (c == "Action") c = "Action";
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
            if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
          }
        }

        function w3AddClass(element, name) {
          var i, arr1, arr2;
          arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
          arr2 = name.split(" ");
          for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
          }
        }

        function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
          var i, arr1, arr2;
          arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
          arr2 = name.split(" ");
          for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
              arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
            }
          }
          element.className = arr1.join(" ");
        }

        // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
        var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
        var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
          btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
          });
        }
```

HTML

```
                  <div class="filter_container text-center" id="myBtnContainer">                            

                        <!-- <div class="filter-item active" data-filter="all">
                            All
                        </div> -->


                          <button class="btn active gradient mt30 color-white color- 
                         white plr50 ptb19" onclick="filterSelection('Action')"> 
                         Action</button>
                          <button class="btn gradient mt30 color-white color-white 
                          plr50 ptb19" onclick="filterSelection('arcade')"> 
                          Arcade</button>
                          <button class="btn gradient mt30 color-white color-white 
                          plr50 ptb19" onclick="filterSelection('Casual')"> 
                          Casual</button>
                          <button class="btn gradient mt30 color-white color-white 
                           plr50 ptb19" onclick="filterSelection('Card')"> 
                            Board</button>                            
                          <button class="btn gradient mt30 color-white color-white 
                           plr50 ptb19" 
                           onclick="filterSelection('Puzzle')">Puzzle</button>
                          <button class="btn gradient mt30 color-white color-white 
                           plr50 ptb19" 
                         onclick="filterSelection('sports')">Sports</button>                              
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                          <?php    
                        //print_r($_SESSION);
                        $url = 'https://viyugames.com/cms/api/index.php?id=1';
                        $data = file_get_contents($url);
                        $characters = json_decode($data, true);

                        foreach($characters['gameslist'] as $key) {
                             if($key['featured']==='0')
                                {
                                  /*if ($key['genre']==='Action') {*/
                                    # code...
                        ?>
                            <div id="div1" class="filterDiv <?PHP echo $key['genre']; 
                         ?> col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <a href="<?PHP echo "game.php?id=".$key['id']; ?>" 
                            target="_blank" class="item-content">
                                    <div class="image-bl">
                                        <img src="<?PHP echo 

                $characters['baseurlthumbnailbanner'].$key['bannericon']; ?>" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom-info text-center p30">
                                        <div class="category fsize-14 fweight-700 
                              uppercase">
                                            <?PHP echo ucfirst($key['genre']); ?> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="img-name">
                                            <h5 data-trim="40">
                                               <?PHP echo $key['name']; ?> 
                                            </h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?PHP
                        /*}*/
                      }
                        else{
                            //echo "no game";
                        }
                        }
                        ?>

                </div>
```

I'm posting full code for better understanding for new people, I hop it will work for somebody. Thanks.